# Private key for ssh in Android application

Tags: android, ssh

I have an android application in which the following happens:

When I press a button, ssh connection gets created with my raspberry pi, the rpi runs a couple of scripts uploads the results to dropbox and the app downloads them from db.

Now, I created a virtual instance in google cloud that I'd like to connect to (instead of the rpi). I can connect to the gc virtual instance in putty, but I need to give my private key to this. My only problem is the ssh private key that I don't know where to put. In my application or is it an easier way?